# Django AJAX GET list via context

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, get

I want to send an array of IDs from my HTML to the Django backend and return the corresponding queryset as context. 
So far I have the following code but it just does not work and I could not find any solution:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form id="select_form" method="get">   
<button type="submit" id="submit_selection_button" .btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_selection_button").click(function() {
    selectedFoo = [1,2];
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    data: {'selected_foo[]': selectedFoo}});
    });
    });
</script>
```

**Django View:**

```
class FooBar(TemplateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        return super(FooBar, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return  super(FooBar, self).get_queryset()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FooBar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        selected_foo = []
        if(self.request.method == "GET"):
            selected_foo = self.request.GET.getlist('selected_foo[]')

        if(selected_foo):
            bar_results = Bar.objects.filter(id__in=selected_foo)
        else:   
            bar_results = Bar.objects.none()

        context = {
            'bar_results': bar_results,
        }
        return  context

foobar = FooBar.as_view()
```

So my problem is that I receive a GET request, but when I try to use "selected_foo" it is just empty. I probably made a mistake in the jQuery part but I'm a beginner and don't know what I did wrong.
Please help me and explain. Thanks

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Comment: change `data: {'selected_foo[]': selectedFoo}});` to `data: {'selected_foo': selectedFoo}});`

Comment: I already tried that. Still no changes. In my view it always goes to the else statement. I'm not sure about the form. Should  there be a method="get" and maybe an action=".." ?

Comment: Try to look for your value in `self.request.query_params` instead of `self.request.GET`

Comment: I think this only works with a REST framework right?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note.  When using Ajax, you should be returning a JSON response (i.e., an HTTP response where Content-type is application/json).  Second, when doing an AJAX call, I typically recommend using POST so that you can pass in JSON using `request.body`.  YMMV.

Update your jQuery to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#submit_selection_button").click(function() {
             selectedFoo = [1,2];
             $.post('/', {'selected_foo': selectedFoo}});
         });
     });
</script>
```

Change your view to:

```
class FooBarAjax(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_foo = json.loads(request.body)
        bar_results = Bar.objects.none()
        if selected_foo:
            bar_results = Bar.objects.filter(id__in=selected_foo)
        return JsonResponse({
            'bar_results': [{
                # serialize Bar to a dict here so that you can pass it
                # back as JSON
            } for result in bar_results]
        })
```